# x86 Assembly "Access violation executing location 0x00000000"

Tags: x86

I have to write an assembly program that will call an external assembly file to generate the amount of prime numbers a user has specified. For now i would like to generate the prime numbers less than 10, and just report that back to the screen, and worry about user input later. The code in genprimes.asm will correctly generate prime numbers and store them into an array. I want to push those onto the stack (see line 79 in genprimes.asm), and recover them after returning from calling that function inside seive.asm. My code works in genprimes.asm if i comment out "push   ecx  ;" on line 79. sieve.asm breaks on line 32, which is the code "call genPrimes". I tried stepping through all my code in "genprimes.asm" and i get to the return statement, then visual studio says i cant debug any further because it doesn't support jumping back to the main file. I dont know why this is breaking. How can i get my prime numbers back to the main file "sieve.asm" that i called "genprimes.asm" from?

sieve.asm:

```
.586
.MODEL FLAT
INCLUDE io.h
EXTERN GenPrimes2:PROC
PUBLIC genPrimes
.STACK 4096                 ; reserve 4096-byte stack
.DATA                       ; reserve storage for data

count    DWORD   ?
sieve    BYTE    10000 DUP(1)
string   BYTE    40 DUP (?)
prompt1  BYTE    "Enter number of primes: ", 0
prompt2  BYTE    "prime number: ", 0
primenum BYTE    11 DUP (?), 0

.CODE

genPrimes   PROC
           ; push   ebp                  ; save base pointer
           ; mov    ebp, esp             ; establish stack frame
           ; push   ebx
            ; CODE
            call GenPrimes2  ;*** breaks here ***

           ; pop    ebx
           ; pop    ebp

            ret                         ;exit genPrimes
genPrimes    ENDP

_sieve  PROC                            ; start of sieve program code

      input   prompt1, string, 40       ; read ASCII characters

      call  genPrimes

      output  prompt2, primenum         ; output label and sum

      mov   eax, 0          ; exit with return code 0
      ret

_sieve  ENDP

END
```

genprimes.asm:

```
.586
.MODEL FLAT


.STACK 4096                 
n=10
.data
    prime DWORD n DUP(?)

.code
GenPrimes2  PROC
mov ebx, 4
mov ecx, 0
loopArray:
    inc ecx
    mov prime[ebx], ecx
    add ebx, 4
    cmp ecx, n
jb  loopArray

mov eax, 3
mov ebx, 2
mov edx, 0

mov ecx,3

sieve_loop:

    cmp eax,ebx
    je skip

    mov edx, 0 ;zero out remainder
    div  ebx
    cmp edx,0 ; if remainder 0, not a prime
    je    NotPrime ;Jump if is a factor, since it cant be prime

; compare eax with n, if equal increment ebx
    cmp ecx,n
    jge    incrementEbx

;  compare ebx with n, if equal end sieve
    cmp ebx, n
    je sieve_end

    inc ecx
    mov eax, ecx

jmp sieve_loop

skip:
inc eax
jmp sieve_loop


NotPrime:
    mov eax, ecx ; store count in eax
    imul ecx, 4
    mov prime[ecx],0
    mov ecx, eax
    inc ecx ; increment ecx count
    inc eax ; increment eax divisor
    jmp sieve_loop

incrementEbx:
inc ebx
mov eax, 3 ; dividend
mov ecx, 3 ; counter

jmp sieve_loop


sieve_end:
    mov ebx, 4
    mov eax, 0
; *************  Add break point on print loop, ecx will be loading with primes and 0's  ********************
; *************  All non-prime numbers have been changed to a 0                          ********************
    PrintLoop:
    mov ecx, prime[ebx] ; Prime numbers are the non-zeros in this Array
    push   ecx  ; **This is somehow breaking it, but doesnt throw and error  
                 ;** when steeping through in Visual Studio?!?
    add ebx, 4
    cmp ebx, 40
    jb  PrintLoop


    mov   eax, 0          ; exit with return code 0
    ret
GenPrimes2 ENDP
END
```

Comment: No i pasted the code into notepad++ to get a line count. Its the one with the code call "GenPrimes2  ;*** breaks here ***" This means that the error should be in genprimes.asm? So i put a break point in the file and it didnt break, and got all the way to the return statement. Visual studio wont let me use the return statement to jump back. So i cant isolate why its breaking. I think its how i am pushing values onto the stack in genprimes.asm in the loop at the bottom of the code. If i comment it out i get no errors, but i can compete the loop without errors using the step through debug feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to learn about calling conventions.

In short: when you do a `call` the IP of next instruction is put on the stack. The `ret` will take the address from the top of the stack and just to that address.

But you are pushing `PUSH CX` so `ret` will find the wrong return address. Usually you return AX (as return value) or you put data before return address. This should be set from caller.

Answer (score 4):

That push ecx instruction is unbalancing your stack. There is no corresponding pop. You are returning to the address given by the last value pushed from ecx instead of the return address. You either need to pop what you pushed or save the sp on entry and restore it before your exit return.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways to return information from a function in an array.

1. Allocate the array in the caller and pass a pointer to the array and its size to the function. Note this allocation can be on the stack, static, or dynamic (e.g., using malloc).
2. Declare a static array in the function and return a pointer to the array from the function.
3. Dynamically allocate the array in the function and return the pointer.
4. In a high level language, return a dynamic array.

Each of these methods has pros and cons. For example, with option 3, the caller has to know that it is responsible for freeing the array when it is done with it.

In your case, since the caller will specify how many values it wants to generate, option 1 is probably the best. In cases where only the called function knows how many items it wants to return, option 3 or 4 is often the best.

---

More details on the pros and cons:

Option 1: The caller must know how much space to reserve. If there is not enough space, the function must return an error or some indication that there are more items. An example of this is sprintf.

Option 2: This can be a good option when the amount of space needed is fixed. But the caller must be aware that if it calls the function twice, the first value is overwritten. An example of this is the C library function ctime, which always returns a fixed-length string.

Option 3: The caller has to know that it is responsible for freeing the array when it is done with it, and it needs to use the same allocator to free the array as the function used to allocate it. An example of this is strdup.

Option 4: This is generally the best option if you are using a language that supports it. For assembly language programming, the infrastructure to implement this can be prohibitively complex, unless it is used enough across the project to make it worth it.